# Parallel computing -- jumbled up output?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to learn the basics of parallel computing, but I'm running into an issue on my computer. Take a look at my code below. Basically, I want to print out the line "Hello World!" for every core my computer has. My computer has four cores, so it should print out that line four times. If I were to use the commented-out 'cout' line instead of the 'printf' line, the output would be all jumbled up. This is because the '\n' escape command is executed separately from the "Hello World!", so the new line output would occur randomly. The 'printf' line is a solution to this problem, because the line is executed all at once (not split up into parts like the 'cout' line). However, when I use 'printf', my output is still all jumbled up as if I used 'cout'. I have no idea why it does this. I tried the exact same code on another computer, and it works perfectly. It's only my computer that continues to jumble up the output with 'printf'. I've emailed my CS professor about it, and he has no idea why it's doing this on my computer. I know I set up OpenMP on my computer correctly. Does anyone with parallel computing experience know why this is messing up on my computer?

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        //cout << "Hello World!\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To show what I'm talking about, here is the output from when I ran the above code on my computer:

> Hello Wo
>
> Hello World!
>
> rld!
>
> Hello World!

Comment: I just tried with `cout` and it worked flawlessly: http://ideone.com/dPPQeO

Comment: The `endl` part maybe your source of problems, as it flushes the output buffer.

Comment: This is pretty much what you should expect to happen when you run things in parallel. There's nothing preventing Core 1's printf from running in the middle of Core 2's. This sort of thing is why parallel programming is hard.

Comment: Certain things need to be run from a single thread, including UI and I/O. Interleaving the I/O as you did can lead to more than just garbled output, it can garble buffer pointers and lead to a real mess.

Comment: What is the problem? This is the expect behaviour

Comment: P.S. there's nothing special about `printf` that prevents a thread from interrupting it when it's half done, despite what your professor or classmates say.

Comment: Mark, my professor specifically said in class that printf fixes the jumbled nature of cout because it's executed all at once. No matter how many times he runs the code in my original post on his computer, it's formatted correctly. This works for everyone else in my class too.

Comment: On some implementation, `printf` will acquire internal lock so it works in parallel, but it is purely implementation details can't be rely on

Comment: @R.Yoder It seems pretty obvious to me that printf is *not* atomic ("executed all at once") since you just demonstrated so.

Comment: Sounds like I'm wrong about printf. I just don't understand why it would be working for everyone else.

Comment: @R.Yoder meet me in chat and I can help explain details. - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c

Comment: @BrianCain -- "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here."

Comment: @BrianCain could you specify what you mean by implementation of printf?

Comment: @BrianCain Thanks for your help in chat, I think I get it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, your professor's mistaken.  You need to leverage mutual exclusion or some other barriers in order to guarantee uninterrupted use of a shared resource (which in this case is the `STDOUT` output file).

Mixed output is potential expected behavior regardless of `printf` or `std::cout::operator<<()`.  The differences in behavior you see are subtle differences in the execution duration of each, due to their differing design.  You should expect this behavior in either case.

> I just don't understand why it would be working for everyone else.

It's not.  Be a hero to your class and explain how it works and how to fix it.  Tell them SO sends their love.  :)

Answer (score 5):

As already explained, the assumption that `printf()` is atomic and won't mangle your output whereas `std::cout::operator<<()` is not and will mess things up if fundamentally wrong.

However, there is still a (tiny) part of "truth" in this, but at a different level. Let me give you an example:

If I try an OpenMP "Hello world" C-style, that might give this:

```
printf( "Hello from thread %d of %d\n",
         omp_get_thread_num(),
         omp_get_num_threads() );
```

The same one C++-style could look like this:

```
std::cout << "Hello from thread " << omp_get_thread_num()
          << " of " << omp_get_num_threads()
          << std::endl;
```

And the essential difference between the two is that for `printf()`, I only call the printing method once, with a fully prepared output string, while the C++-style one will call `std::cout::operator<<()` 5 times, with only bits and pieces of lines that may or may not be sent to the standard output.
Internally, anything can happen and I won't try to commit on any sort of behaviour. But at least by using `printf()` here, I increase my chances of a clean output, even if I cannot guaranty it.

Here is a full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    printf( "Hello from thread %d of %d with printf()\n",
             omp_get_thread_num(),
             omp_get_num_threads() );

    printf( "*** outside of parallel region ***\n" );

    #pragma omp parallel
    std::cout << "Hello from thread " << omp_get_thread_num()
              << " of " << omp_get_num_threads()
              << " with std::cout"
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which on my Linux laptop gives me (GCC 5.2):

```
~/tmp$ g++ -fopenmp stdout.cc
~/tmp$ ./a.out 
Hello from thread 3 of 4 with printf()
Hello from thread 0 of 4 with printf()
Hello from thread 2 of 4 with printf()
Hello from thread 1 of 4 with printf()
*** outside of parallel region ***
Hello from thread Hello from thread Hello from thread Hello from thread 1 of 4 with std::cout23 of 4 with std::cout
 of 4 with std::cout
0 of 4 with std::cout

~/tmp$
```

If you look carefully, you can see that none of the individual calls to `std::cout::operator<<()` is split, but each new call is an opportunity for the various threads to races each-other, and to get the output mangled.

So again, telling that `printf()` is atomic and won't mess things up is wrong, but simply, for a complex output string, it is less likely to be mangled than with `std::cout`.