# output file using openmp for loop

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm using openmp to parallelize a for loop which calculates some values and I want to write the results in one output file (the order doesn't matter). the simplified version of the code I'm using is as following;

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(n=0; n<M; n++){
 // calculate some parameters, e.g. a,b,c,d
 // now write them in the output file which is already opened using the config.dat file
outfile << setprecision(8) << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " << d << "\n";
}

outfile.close();
```

most of the time I receive the right outfile but sometimes I have broken lines in the outfile or some lines seem to be mixed up which I guess is due to the fact that more than one core try to write in the output file at the same time.
I would be really grateful if someone can tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: wrap `outfile <<...` with `#pragma omp critical`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665044/5239503) for a explanation of what's happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As written in one of the comments, you will need a mutex.

However, if you are going to dump large amounts of data, using

```
#pragma omp critical
```

could have a large performance impact.

Consider a solution where each thread stores X lines in a private buffer and dumps them all to file in one batch.